# Binary Heap: Height of subtree rooted at position i

Tags: algorithm, heap, binary-heap

Given n values I created a Binary Max-Heap. I want to know the formula to calculate height of subtree rooted at any position i.

Answer (score 0):

Each level in complete binary heap has 2^i nodes , so any binary heap must have 2^i nodes in level (i) except last level.

```
..............................(100)...................  2^0 nodes
............................./.....\..................  
...........................(19)...(36)................  2^1
........................../...\.../...\...............
.......................(17)..(3).(25).(1).............  2^2
......................./..\...........................
.....................(2).(7)..........................  last level.
```

because last level may be not complete so `n < 2^h`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The level of any node at position `k` is `floor(log2(k + 1))`.

So the height of the subtree rooted at position `i` is the difference of levels (assuming that a single leaf has height 0): `height = floor(log2(n + 1)) - floor(log2(i + 1))`.

We need to check if the subtree reaches the bottom of the heap or if it is one level shorter. We do this by comparing the left-most leaf to the last element:

```
if(pow(2, height) * (i + 1) - 1 >= n)
    height--;
```

Answer (score 0):

simple algorithm:- go left till you hit null. this can be done in binary heap by `left = 2*parent`. The time complexity of algorithm is `O(logn)`. Moreover you can directly evaluate it using following inequality :-  `2^k*i < N   , k < log2(N/i) , k = log2(floor(N/i))` . The above calculation can be done efficiently in `O(log(log(n)))` where you need to do binary search on the highest bit set in `floor(N/i)`.

Finding highest bit set in integer :-

```
high = 63
low = 0
mid = 0
while(low<high) {

  mid = (low+high)>>1
  val = 1<<mid
  if(val==mid)
    return mid
  if(val>mid) {
     high = mid-1
  }
  else low = mid+1
}

return mid
```